# Problem with systemd & ksoftirqd

Tags: systemd

I've a server which runs `Debian 8`. I think there's something wrong with `systemd` & `ksoftirqd`.
In fact, if I perform a `systemctl's` command (like `systemctl mysql restart`) it returns nothing and I have to press `CTRL+C`.

If I perform the command `journalctl -x -e`, I get A LOT of these logs:

```
apr 06 18:50:27 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:28 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:29 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:31 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:32 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:33 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:35 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:36 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:38 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 06 18:50:39 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
```

Also, they use an unusual (I think) amount of CPU:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0   28888   4404   2436 S  12,0  0,1 170:25.27 systemd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   7,6  0,0 101:50.61 ksoftirqd/0
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1,0  0,0 104:21.05 ksoftirqd/1
```

Finally, here's the logs right before the huge spam of `Looping too fast. [...]`:

```
apr 05 21:17:02 MrJonhs CRON[13469]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
apr 05 21:17:02 MrJonhs CRON[13470]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
apr 05 21:17:02 MrJonhs CRON[13469]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
apr 05 21:18:09 MrJonhs sshd[13453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user admin
apr 05 21:19:19 MrJonhs systemd-logind[18619]: Failed to abandon session scope: Connection timed out
apr 05 21:22:16 MrJonhs systemd-logind[18619]: Removed session 269.
-- Subject: The session with ID 269 was terminated.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- The session with ID 269 was terminated.
apr 05 21:22:16 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 05 21:22:33 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 05 21:22:46 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 05 21:22:58 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 05 21:23:01 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
apr 05 21:23:05 MrJonhs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
```

What could be the problem?